WindowsStoreでインストールしたPython3.12を使って、PowerShell上で`python`コマンドを実行したいです
環境

Windows 10 Home(22H2)
Python 3.12

やりたいこと
Widows StoreでPython3.12をインストールしました。
https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NCVDN91XZQP?ocid=pdpshare
PowerShell上で以下の様にpythonコマンドを実行したいです。
> python sample.py

やったこと

Windows Storeでインストールしたpython.exeをパスに通すため、python.exeの存在するディレクトリに移動しました。
ディレクトリのパスは、Python 3.12アプリのウィンドウの上部に表示されるパスから調べました。
> cd C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0

>dir
 ドライブ C のボリューム ラベルは Windows です
 ボリューム シリアル番号は 80CE-8290 です

 C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0 のディレクトリ

2024/03/07  11:51    <DIR>          .
2024/03/07  11:51    <DIR>          ..
2024/03/07  11:49         1,186,069 AppxBlockMap.xml
2024/03/07  11:49             9,133 AppxManifest.xml
2024/03/07  11:49    <DIR>          AppxMetadata
2024/03/07  11:49            12,035 AppxSignature.p7x
2024/01/10  06:13            23,092 classicAppCompat.sccd
2024/03/07  11:49    <DIR>          DLLs
2024/03/07  11:50           158,488 idle3.12.exe
2024/03/07  11:49    <DIR>          include
2024/03/07  11:49    <DIR>          Lib
2024/03/07  11:49    <DIR>          libs
2024/01/10  06:13            36,874 LICENSE.txt
2024/03/07  11:51           160,024 pip3.12.exe
2024/03/07  11:51           160,024 python.exe
2024/03/07  11:51           160,024 python3.12.exe
2024/03/07  11:51            68,376 python3.dll
2024/03/07  11:51         7,009,048 python312.dll
2024/03/07  11:51           158,488 pythonw.exe
2024/03/07  11:51           158,488 pythonw3.12.exe
2024/03/07  11:51           721,768 resources.pri
2024/03/07  11:49    <DIR>          tcl
2023/12/14  15:13           119,192 vcruntime140.dll
2024/01/10  06:13            49,528 vcruntime140_1.dll
2024/03/07  11:49    <DIR>          _resources
              16 個のファイル          10,190,651 バイト
               9 個のディレクトリ  18,542,575,616 バイトの空き領域



ディレクトリに存在するpython.exeを実行すると、「アクセスが拒否されました。」というメッセージが出力されました。
>python.exe --version
アクセスが拒否されました。

質問
WindowsストアでインストールしたPythonを、PowerShell上で実行するにはどうすればよいでしょうか？
また、PowerShell上でpython.exeを実行すると、「アクセスが拒否されました。」というメッセージが出力されたのは、なぜでしょうか？（Windows Storeでインストールされたアプリだから？）
補足

Pythonの公式サイトからインストールすれば、問題は解決します。ただ、そのためにPythonを再インストールするのは面倒だったので、質問しました。
以下のドキュメントによると、Windows StoreからPython3.12をインストールした場合PowerShellからコマンドが実行できるようです。しかし、私の環境では実行できません（パスが通っていない）でした。インストールしたのは数カ月前なので、このドキュメント通り実行したかは覚えていません。


Python がダウンロードとインストールのプロセスを完了したら、スタート メニュー (左下の Windows アイコン) を使用して Windows PowerShell を開きます。 PowerShell が開いたら、Python --version を入力して、マシンに Python3 がインストールされていることを確認します。

https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/python/beginners
追記
Delft Viewさんの回答に従い、sys.executableの結果を確認しました。
Python 3.12.2 (tags/v3.12.2:6abddd9, Feb  6 2024, 21:26:36) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\yuji3\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe'


WindowsApps フォルダは通常開けないようになっているので、この配下で実行しようとしているのが間違いな気もします。Store からインストール後、PowerShell を開いてそのまま python コマンドを実行すれば問題ありませんでした。

通常，Python の実行バイナリの絶対バスは sys.executable に格納されているので，アプリを起動して下記を入力するとインストール場所がわかると思われます。これを基に環境変数 Path を設定してください。
>> import sys
>> sys.executable


sys.executableの結果を確認したところ、%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps配下のpython.exeを実行していたようです。
このパスを環境変数PATHに設定したら、python --versionを実行することができました。

自PCのWindows11では、正常に実行できました。
Microsoft Storeの公式アプリの場合、'%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps`下に実行用のリンクが作成されます。
上記のパスをユーザー側のPath環境変数に追加して実行してみたらどうでしょう
